When is an ergodic Ito diffusion also mixing
If $(X_t,t\geq0)$ denotes the strong solution to the Ito SDE $\mathrm{d}X_t=b(X_t)\mathrm{d}t+\sigma(X_t)\mathrm{d}W_t$ for $W_t$ the standard $d$-dimensional Brownian motion and $b,\sigma$ satisfying the usual conditions with $X_0=x$ and $\sigma$ additionally satisfies the uniform hypoelliptic assumption. Additionally, we assume that $X_t$ is ergodic in the sense that the semigroup $P_t$ converges to the invariant probability measure $\mu$ in total variation norm.
I am curious what conditions we need to impose on the process in order to obtain that $X_t$ additionally satisfies mixing properties (for example one of the mixing concepts in Basic Properties of Strong Mixing Conditions. A Survey and Some Open Questions). Intuition says that there must exist some argument to argue that indeed ergodicity induces sufficient "regularity" on the trajectories to ensure some form of mixing. For example, example 2.2.18 in the book Stochastic
Processes and Long Range Dependence argues that a centered stationary Gaussian process $(X_n,n\in\mathbb{Z})$ is ergodic if and only if it is weakly mixing. Indeed the class of Gaussian processes could be considered one of the "nicest" processes to work with, yet the Ito diffusion inherets many of the welcoming properties of the Brownian motion, and so I feel that a similar result should exist for the Ito diffusion (perhaps under additional (mild) assumptions).
Could my intuition be right, and does anyone know any sources which might contain more information?

Hi: I don't know if it's advanced enough to cover what you're talking about but you could try Davidson's "Stochastic Limit Theory" and see if that has anything. I would look but the book is in storage.

Mixing properties are related to the rate of ergodicity.
For example, the strong mixing coefficient of any stationary Markov process can be bounded by 'mean total variation':
$$
\alpha(n)\le\int_E\|P^n(x,-)-\mu\|_{\mathrm{TV}}\mu(dx).
$$
For reference, see Proposition 5.1.1 on page 159 of Kulik (2018).
For a stationary Gaussian process to be weakly mixing, as you pointed out, it must be ergodic, whereas for it to be mixing (in an ergodic theoretical sense), that is,
$$
\biggl|\mathbb{P}[X_{n+k}\in A,X_{k}\in B]-\mathbb{P}[X_{k+n}\in A]\,\mathbb{P}[X_k\in B]\biggr|\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0,\quad(A,B\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})),
$$
its covariance must vanish in the limit: $\operatorname{Cov}[X_{k+n},X_k]\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0$ (example 2.2.8, page 43 in Samorodnitsky (2016)).
Lastly, for it to be $\phi$-mixing (the strongest concept among these), its covariance has to vanish whithin a finite range: there exists $N\ge1$ such that $\sigma[X_k|k\le m]\perp\!\!\,\!\perp\sigma[X_{k+n}|k\ge m]$ for all $n\ge N$ (Theorem 17.3.2, page 312 in Ibragimov and Linnik (1971) Independent and Stationary Sequences of Random Variables). And in turn the $\phi$-mixing coefficient can be bounded by total variation norm as follows:
$$
\phi(n)\le\sup_{x\in E}\|P^n(x,-)-\mu\|_\text{TV}.
$$
Consequently, for an ergodic process to satisfy stronger mixing conditions, it has to converge to stationary more rapidly (and more uniformly).
